# Glass Mapper is not returning all results

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore8.1

I'm struggling with Glass Mapper and can find little on Google. My class has a property that should get all descendant news articles:

```
[SitecoreQuery(".//*[@@templateid='{6F15C485-CA13-4352-A411-7F36447CC879}']", IsRelative = true, IsLazy = true)]
IEnumerable<IArticle> DescendantArticles { get; set; }
```

There should be about 850 arranged in folders named by year and then by month number but I am only getting 260 results.
I have tried following the query format set out in [Tutorial 7](http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial7):

```
[SitecoreQuery("./*/*/*[@@templateid='{6F15C485-CA13-4352-A411-7F36447CC879}']", IsRelative = true, IsLazy = true)]
```

Still no dice. If I try:

```
[SitecoreQuery("./2015/*/*[@@te...
```

I will get all of 2015's articles, so they are all published but when trying to get the lot, I still only get the first 200 articles (2010-2011!). I have tried altering:

```
<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100" />
```

With no result. I fear I've missed something. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are running a Sitecore Query the number of items returned is limited by the `Query.MaxItems` setting:

```
<!--  Query.MaxItems
        Specifies the max number of items in a query result set.
        If the number is 0, all items are returned. This may affect system performance, if a
        large query result is returned.
        This also controls the number of items in Lookup, Multilist and Valuelookup fields.
        Default value: 100
  -->
<setting name="Query.MaxItems" value="100"/>
```

This value from `Sitecore.config` is in turn patched by the setting in `Sitecore.ExperienceExplorer.config` which sets the value to 260, this was updated in Sitecore 8.1. That is why you only have that many items returned.

Either increase this value or it would be better to reevaluate your code to use ContentSearch API. Turning this value up too high will negatively affect performance.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.